# Getting Error 24 'CapSample.MW' does not have a suitable static Main method

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# winforms  app where I have a solution that contains three projects. When build the solution I face the above specified error.  I googled it and found that there should be a main method which is the entry point for every program. However i included program.cs file in my solution and it does have main method. How can I add main method for all three projects in the solution. currently its giving error only for one project why don't it throw errors for other two projects. Any suggestions to fix this will be really appreciated. Here is the code of the project:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DirectX.Capture;
namespace CapSample
{

    public partial class MW : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    { 

        #region " Código generado por el Diseñador de Windows Forms "

        public MW() : base()
        {

            //El Diseñador de Windows Forms requiere esta llamada.
            InitializeComponent();

            //Call to AddCam to select an available camera
            AddCam AddCamera = new AddCam();
            AddCamera.ShowDialog(this);

            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.PreviewWindow = this.videoBoard;

            //Define RefreshImage as event handler of FrameCaptureComplete
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.FrameCaptureComplete += RefreshImage;

            ModCap.CaptureInformation.Counter = 1;
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CounterFrames = 1;


            this.Show();

            //Initialization of ConfWindow
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.ConfWindow = new CW();
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.ConfWindow.Refresh();
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.ConfWindow.Show();

        }

        //Form reemplaza a Dispose para limpiar la lista de componentes.
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing) {
                if ((components != null)) {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        //Requerido por el Diseñador de Windows Forms

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        //NOTA: el Diseñador de Windows Forms requiere el siguiente procedimiento
        //Puede modificarse utilizando el Diseñador de Windows Forms. 
        //No lo modifique con el editor de código.
        internal System.Windows.Forms.Panel videoBoard;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button withEventsField_cmdFrame;
    /*  internal System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdFrame {
            get { return withEventsField_cmdFrame; }
            set {
                if (withEventsField_cmdFrame != null) {
                    withEventsField_cmdFrame.Click -= cmdFrame_Click;
                }
                withEventsField_cmdFrame = value;
                if (withEventsField_cmdFrame != null) {
                    withEventsField_cmdFrame.Click += cmdFrame_Click;
                }
            }
        }*/
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button withEventsField_cmdStart;
        internal System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdStart {
            get { return withEventsField_cmdStart; }
            set {
                if (withEventsField_cmdStart != null) {
                    withEventsField_cmdStart.Click -= cmdStart_Click;
                }
                withEventsField_cmdStart = value;
                if (withEventsField_cmdStart != null) {
                    withEventsField_cmdStart.Click += cmdStart_Click;
                }
            }
        }

        private Button btnStart;
        private Button btnFrame;

        private Button cmdFrame;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button withEventsField_cmdStop;
        private Button btnStop;
       // private Button cmdStart;
     //   private Button cmdFrame;
//private Button cmdStart;

        /*internal System.Windows.Forms.Button cmdStop {
            get { return withEventsField_cmdStop; }
            set {
                if (withEventsField_cmdStop != null) {
                    withEventsField_cmdStop.Click -= cmdStop_Click;
                }
                withEventsField_cmdStop = value;
                if (withEventsField_cmdStop != null) {
                    withEventsField_cmdStop.Click += cmdStop_Click;
                }
            }
        }*/
        internal System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pcbFrame;
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.videoBoard = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.pcbFrame = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.btnStop = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnFrame = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pcbFrame)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // videoBoard
            // 
            this.videoBoard.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(2, 0);
            this.videoBoard.Name = "videoBoard";
            this.videoBoard.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240);
            this.videoBoard.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // pcbFrame
            // 
            this.pcbFrame.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.pcbFrame.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(334, 0);
            this.pcbFrame.Name = "pcbFrame";
            this.pcbFrame.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240);
            this.pcbFrame.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            this.pcbFrame.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pcbFrame.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // btnStop
            // 
            this.btnStop.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 246);
            this.btnStop.Name = "btnStop";
            this.btnStop.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnStop.TabIndex = 6;
            this.btnStop.Text = "Stop";
            this.btnStop.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnStop.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStop_Click);
            // 
            // btnStart
            // 
            this.btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(34, 246);
            this.btnStart.Name = "btnStart";
            this.btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnStart.TabIndex = 7;
            this.btnStart.Text = "Start";
            this.btnStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStart_Click);
            // 
            // btnFrame
            // 
            this.btnFrame.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(376, 246);
            this.btnFrame.Name = "btnFrame";
            this.btnFrame.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnFrame.TabIndex = 8;
            this.btnFrame.Text = "Frame";
            this.btnFrame.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnFrame.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFrame_Click);
            // 
            // MW
            // 
            this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 13);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(656, 289);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnFrame);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnStart);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnStop);
            this.Controls.Add(this.pcbFrame);
            this.Controls.Add(this.videoBoard);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "MW";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Main Window";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pcbFrame)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public void RefreshImage(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox Frame)
        {
            string[] s = null;
            s = ModCap.CaptureInformation.PathVideo.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            this.pcbFrame.Image = Frame.Image;
            this.pcbFrame.Image.Save(s[0] + Convert.ToString(ModCap.CaptureInformation.CounterFrames) + ".png");
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CounterFrames += 1;
            this.pcbFrame.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.Start();
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnFrame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.Stop();
            ModCap.ConfParamCam();
            ModCap.PrepareCam(ModCap.CaptureInformation.PathVideo);
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

    /*  private void cmdFrame_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.CaptureFrame();
        }

        private void cmdStart_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.Start();
            cmdStart.Enabled = false;
            cmdStop.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void cmdStop_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ModCap.CaptureInformation.CaptureInfo.Stop();
            ModCap.ConfParamCam();
            ModCap.PrepareCam(ModCap.CaptureInformation.PathVideo);
            cmdStart.Enabled = true;
            cmdStop.Enabled = false;
        }*/

    }
}
```